# Android: UUID cannot serialize

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2, uuid

I'm trying to pass a UUID to a web service but when i try to send every parameter it return an error that says cannot serialize and then it appears the values of the UUID, unless i pass it as a string value like there is in the code but when it send to the web service it gives the unexpected type text stream reader error

Here's the code if any of you could help i would aprecciate it:

```
 package go.pw.exe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class Ex1Activity extends Activity {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION="http://vitalcare.hydra.pt/IHealthRecordService/CreateWeightRecord";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CreateWeightRecord";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://vitalcare.hydra.pt/";
    private static final String URL = "http://www.hydra.pt:8070/HealthRecordService.svc?wsdl";

    Calendar c;
    String data;
    TextView msg;
    UUID weightId;
    Button send;
    EditText weight;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_weight);

        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {  


                int userWeight = Integer.valueOf(weight.getText().toString());
                c = Calendar.getInstance();
                weightId= UUID.randomUUID(); 
                data = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+ "-" + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-"+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+ " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                String Id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                request.addProperty("UserId", "3e1c7765-7370-4295-8170-92a1d2dc542c");
                request.addProperty("CreationDate", data);
                request.addProperty("WeightId", Id);
                request.addProperty("When", data);
                request.addProperty("WeightInKilos", userWeight);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet=true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                try{
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);  
           }  
           catch (Exception e) {  
             e.printStackTrace();
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  }  
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can u tell how you have solved your problem?